# How to return value from async method in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

I have the following flask app:

```
async def run():
   conn = await asyncpg.connect(db_url)
   values = await conn.fetch('''SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;''')
   await conn.close()

@app.route('/')
def test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    res = loop.run_until_complete(run())
    return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in res]) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run this code I got `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. How to return my `values` converted to JSON?

Comment: in this code, is it okay that `test()` function is not async?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to return your values in your `run` function for them to be available in `test`:

```
async def run():
   conn = await asyncpg.connect(db_url)
   values = await conn.fetch('''SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;''')
   await conn.close()
   return values
```

Comment: Thanks, is it necessary to return value after `await conn.close()` or I can `return values` and then `await conn.close()` ?

Comment: `return` exits the function, so the `await` would not be called. Maybe try `yield values` before calling `await conn.close()`.

Comment: On second thought: what you probably want to do is `loop.create_task(conn.close())` and still use `return values`. This will schedule the closing of the connection without waiting for it in your function.